# Redis Node JS - storing multiple objects of the same class

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, hashmap

I want to store all objects of a class in redis cache and be able to retrive them, as I understand hashmaps are used for storing objects, but they are require a different key to be saved. So I can't save them all under key e.g. "items" and retrieve them by that key. Only way I can do it is something like this:

```
items.forEach(item => {
    redis.hmset(`item${item.id}`, item);
}
```

But this feels wrong and I have to have a for loop again when I want to get this data. Is there a better solution? 
Also there is a problem of associated objects, I can't find anywhere how they are stored and used in redis.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to save different keys with same prefix
[You can use mset to store them](https://redis.io/commands/mset)

For retrieving the data you use the [mget
with your keys as params](https://redis.io/commands/mget)

In case you still want to use the hmset
Use pipline in the loop
So the call to redis will be only one with the sync action

Comment: I have to store objects so I'm not sure how would mset work for me. And I'm not sure that you mean by "call to redis will be only one with the sync action".

Comment: When you want to get the data back, use the for loop with pipeline.hmget
https://redis.io/topics/pipelining
You don't have another way beside the loop